# Node.js - How do I limit the file upload size of a multipart form in formidable

Tags: node.js, forms, post, formidable

I know formidable has a `form.maxFieldsSize`, but that doesn't include files. How would I limit the maximum file size uploaded to a multipart form in formidable, and terminate the form if the file size is too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the code down below for that kind of task.

```
var sizeLimitBytes = 2000;
form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
  if(bytesReceived > sizeLimitBytes ){
    return false; //exit the program
  }
});
```

Comment: don't you want to exit the program if `bytesReceived > mySize` ? instead of `bytesReceived < mySize` ?

Comment: are you sure you need to tally a total? Docs say bytesReceived is `The amount of bytes received for this form so far.` so it sounds like it already is a "total" https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable